# merge two table in R by by implicit columns

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I have two tables

```
tab1=structure(list(generated_id = c(482160724447511, 482160724447511
), utc_time = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "30.09.2018 12:46", class = "factor"), 
    local_time = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "30.09.2018 15:46", class = "factor"), 
    user_locale = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "en", class = "factor"), 
    network = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "Facebook Installs", class = "factor"), 
    campaign = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "(GR23)(BGM)(AND)(FB)(App Events)(US)(W35+)(27.09.2018) (23843105742120752)", class = "factor"), 
    adgroup = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "(GR23)(BGM)(AND)(FB)(META)(US)(W35+)(NONE)(APP_EV)(NONE)(PURCHASE)(NONE)(27.09.2018) (23843105743590752)", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

tab2=
structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "10.10.2018", class = "factor"), 
    campaign_id = c(2.38431e+16, 2.38431e+16), ad_set_id = c(2.38431e+16, 
    2.38431e+16), spent = c(1.77, 13.85)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

tab2$campaign_id=tab1$campaign
tab2$ad_set_id=tab1$adgroup
```

usually i use sinple function merge

```
merge(tab1,tab2 , by =c("campaign", "adgroup"
))
```

But in this case i have difficult, becase `tab1$campaign` has id at the end in brackets

```
(GR23)(BGM)(AND)(FB).... (***23843105743590752***)


(GR23)(BGM)(AND)(FB)(META)(US)(W35+)(NONE)(APP_EV)(NONE)(PURCHASE)(NONE)(27.09.2018) (***23843105743590752***)
```

where (*** *** ) it is id for merge

How can i in this case ,merge tab1 and tab2 by campaign and adgroup if in tab1 key id at the end in brackets?

Comment: To merge two data frames you need at least one column name in common, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Set `by.x` and `by.y` appropriately.

Comment: The `tab1` example you give contains 2 identical rows. Is that a representative case? Furthermore the id's `campaign_id` and `ad_set_id` in `tab2` are in scientific notation which results into no matching id's in both data.frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem now is to merge the tables on substrings of columns.
One way to achieve this to extract that substring and add it to `tab1`.

Since the rows in `tab1` are identical and the id's in `tab2` didn't match any of `tab1`, I used different sets:

```
tab1 <- structure(list(campaign = c("(GR23)(BGM)(AND)(FB)(App Events)(US)(W35+)(27.09.2018) (23843105742120752)", 
                                    "(GR23)(BGM)(AND)(FB)(App Events)(US)(W35+)(27.09.2018) (23843105742120753)"), 
                       adgroup = c("(GR23)(BGM)(AND)(FB)(META)(US)(W35+)(NONE)(APP_EV)(NONE)(PURCHASE)(NONE)(27.09.2018) (23843105743590752)", 
                                   "(GR23)(BGM)(AND)(FB)(META)(US)(W35+)(NONE)(APP_EV)(NONE)(PURCHASE)(NONE)(27.09.2018) (23843105743590752)"), 
                       generated_id = c(482160724447511, 482160724447511)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
tab2 <- structure(list(campaign_id = c("23843105742120752", "23843105742120753"), 
                       ad_set_id = c("23843105743590752", "23843105743590752"), 
                       date = c("10.10.2018", "10.10.2018"), spent = c(1.77, 13.85)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")


# Create a function that extracts the id from the last part
extract_id <- function(x){
  s <- strsplit(as.character(x), " ")
  s_id <- sapply(s, function(si) si[length(si)])
  ids <- gsub("[^[:digit:] ]", "", s_id) # Remove all but digits/numbers
  return(ids)
}

# Add the extracted id's to tab1
tab1$campaign_id <- extract_id(tab1$campaign)
tab1$adgroup_id <- extract_id(tab1$adgroup)

# Your result
result <- merge(tab1, tab2, 
                by.x = c("campaign_id", "adgroup_id"), 
                by.y = c("campaign_id", "ad_set_id"))
```

Please note that besides different values, some columns also have different types. I.e. `character` instead of `factor`.